# R: evaluating multiple conditionals multiple times

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I have data like this:

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(
  event1 = c(88.76,96.04,99.60,88.76,99.60,34.04,96.04,87.03,87.44,87.44),
  time1 = c(0.100,0.033,0.000,0.117,0.000,0.000,0.050,0.500,0.133,0.117),
  event2 = c(NA,99.60,NA,34.04,99.62,88.76,87.44,87.41,88.76,88.76),
  time2 = c(NA,0.050,NA,0.100,0.017,0.083,0.200,0.500,0.133,0.050),
  event100 = c(NA,89.52,NA,34.04,93.93,34.02,88.76,88.01,88.01,87.41),
  time100 = c(NA,0.050,NA,0.100,0.033,0.117,0.300,0.500,0.233,0.300),
  event_88.76_within_0.1 = rep(0,10)
))
```

where `event1` is the code for the first event a subject had and `time1` is how long it took before `event1` happened, and each subject has up to 100 events and times to events.

I am trying to create a variable (`event_88.76_within_0.1`) that indicates if event 88.76 happened within 0.1 minutes.  So it would equal 1 if any of a subject's events equals 88.76 and the corresponding time to event is less than or equal to 0.1.

Using this nested `for` loop:

```
for(r in 1:nrow(df)){ #for each subject
  for(c in 1:6){ #for each event
    if( !is.na(df[r, c]) & df[r, c] == 88.76 & df[r,(c+1)] <= 0.1){
#if the event code is not missing and if it's the needed event code and
#the next column over (the corresponding time to event) is less than 0.1
      df[r,"event_88.76_within_0.1"] = 1   
    } 
    i = i + 2  #skip 2 columns to get to next event code
  }
}
```

I can get this, which is what I want:

```
      event1 time1 event2 time2 event100 time100 event_88.76_within_0.1
 [1,]  88.76 0.100     NA    NA       NA      NA                      1
 [2,]  96.04 0.033  99.60 0.050    89.52   0.050                      0
 [3,]  99.60 0.000     NA    NA       NA      NA                      0
 [4,]  88.76 0.117  34.04 0.100    34.04   0.100                      0
 [5,]  99.60 0.000  99.62 0.017    93.93   0.033                      0
 [6,]  34.04 0.000  88.76 0.083    34.02   0.117                      1
 [7,]  96.04 0.050  87.44 0.200    88.76   0.300                      0
 [8,]  87.03 0.500  87.41 0.500    88.01   0.500                      0
 [9,]  87.44 0.133  88.76 0.133    88.01   0.233                      0
[10,]  87.44 0.117  88.76 0.050    87.41   0.300                      1
```

But the data set has thousands of subjects (each with 100 possible events), so the nested `for` loops take a while to run.

I would like to vectorize the above loop to something like this:

```
df$event_88.76_within_0.1 = 0
df$event_88.76_within_0.1[df[ "events that equal 88.76 and occurred within 0.1" ]]=1
```

but I haven't had any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
## Define the names of your events and times columns
events = paste0("event",c(1,2,100))
times = paste0("time",c(1,2,100))
## Check if your two conditions are met and multiply the results (multiplying TRUE by TRUE gives 1, multiplying TRUE or FALSE by FALSE returns 0)
df$event_88.76_within_0.1 = pmin(1,rowSums((df[,events]==88.76)*(df[,times]<=0.1),na.rm=T))

   event1 time1 event2 time2 event100 time100 event_88.76_within_0.1
1   88.76 0.100     NA    NA       NA      NA                      1
2   96.04 0.033  99.60 0.050    89.52   0.050                      0
3   99.60 0.000     NA    NA       NA      NA                      0
4   88.76 0.117  34.04 0.100    34.04   0.100                      0
5   99.60 0.000  99.62 0.017    93.93   0.033                      0
6   34.04 0.000  88.76 0.083    34.02   0.117                      1
7   96.04 0.050  87.44 0.200    88.76   0.300                      0
8   87.03 0.500  87.41 0.500    88.01   0.500                      0
9   87.44 0.133  88.76 0.133    88.01   0.233                      0
10  87.44 0.117  88.76 0.050    87.41   0.300                      1
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks.

Comment: Bah!  You beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Lamia, great answer! One small suggestion: if the conditions holds `n` times per row you'll get `n` instead of `1`. I suggest wrapping an `ifelse` around it, or around the final variable, something like `ifelse(rowSums((df[,events]==88.76)*(df[,times]<=0.1),na.rm=T)>0, 1, 0) `

Comment: @MattTyers Sorry .. :)

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis You're right, I understood from the OP description that the 88.76 event could only occur once per row, as each event is different. If not, then one can include an ifelse as you suggested or a `pmin(1,rowSums((df[,events]==88.76)*(df[,times]<=0.1),na.rm=‌​T))`. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ball of duct tape...

```
cond1 <- df[,seq(1,6,by=2)]==88.76
cond2 <- df[,seq(2,6,by=2)]<=0.1
vec <- which(rowSums(cond1 & cond2, na.rm=T)==1)

df[vec,]
##    event1 time1 event2 time2 event100 time100
## 1   88.76 0.100     NA    NA       NA      NA 
## 6   34.04 0.000  88.76 0.083    34.02   0.117 
## 10  87.44 0.117  88.76 0.050    87.41   0.300
```

Comment: Also a great answer (I like the option of making it a bit more flexible by using the column numbers instead of @Lamia's naming approach) but Lamia beat you by a minute.